# Increasing continuous but non-differentiable function

Tags: calculus

If a function is continuous but maybe non-differentiable in countable number of points, what are the conditions on the function to be monotonically increasing?

For a differentiable function, 
$$f'\ge0 \iff   f \text{ increasing.}$$

What if differentiability does not hold in some of the domain points?

Comment: Why not : $x_2>x_1 \Rightarrow f(x_2)>f(x_1)$ ?

Comment: There is really nothing else one can do. Continuity does not seem to give anything with which one might hope to characterize monotonicity

Comment: How about comparing the left and right limit of the slope or their signs at kinks?